# Add and set total value in corresponding input field

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-calculation

I'm trying to add the values in child rows in one column which should set the total in the parent row of that column. Each child `td` should add the value in the corresponding parent `td`.

What is happening right now is while I can add up the values of a child rows in the first column and set the total in the corresponding input field of the parent row; if I then add up the values of the child rows in the second column, it doesn't set the value in the parent of the second column. It adds up to the parent of the first column.

Here's the code [[jsFiddle]](http://jsfiddle.net/Ur99Q/1/):

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table">
<tr class="parent-A">
        <td><h5>A</h5></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h6>A1</h6></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="A" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="A"  /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="A"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h6>A2</h6></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="A" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="A"  /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="A"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h6>A3</h6></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="A" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="A"  /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="A" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent-B">
        <td><h5>B</h5></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h6>B1</h6></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="B" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="B"  /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="B"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h6>B2</h6></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="B" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="B"  /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="B"  /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><h6>B3</h6></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="B" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="B"  /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input type="text" data-parent="B" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('input[type=text]').on('blur', function() {

    var $dataRows=$(".table");
    var parent_name = $(this).attr('data-parent');
    var find_parent_row = $('tr.parent-' + parent_name);
    var $this_row = $(this).closest('tr');

        $this_row.each(function() {
            $(this).find('input').each(function(i){        
                totals[i]+=parseInt( $(this).val());
                console.log(totals[i]);
                var eVal = (isNaN(totals[i])) ? 0 : totals[i];
                $(find_parent_row).find('input').eq(i).val(eVal);
            });

        });

    });



});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/a3J8U/)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $('[class*="parent-"] input').attr('readonly', true);
    $('input[type=text]').on('blur', function () {
        var totals = [0, 0, 0];
        var $dataRows = $(".table");
        var parent_name = $(this).data('parent');
        var find_parent_row = $('tr.parent-' + parent_name);
        find_parent_row.nextUntil('[class*="parent-"]').find('input').each(function () {
            totals[$(this).parent('td').index() / 2 - 1] += +this.value;
        });
        find_parent_row.find('input').each(function(i) {
            this.value = totals[i];
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you once again. I just had a small question. How would I add up the parent `A` + `B` of all the 3 columns and set their value in the total row in their corresponding input fields?

Comment: @input POST A NEW QUESTION .i will help you .